# How to prove divergence using alternating series test? $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm able to show it isn't absolutely convergent as the sequence $\{1^n\}$ clearly doesn't converge to $0$ as it is just an infinite sequence of $1$'s. How do I prove the series isn't conditionally convergent to prove divergence!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A real series $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n$ is conditionally convergent if, by definition, $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}|a_n|=+\infty$ AND the limit of its partial sums exists; i.e. iff
$$
\exists\lim_nS_n\in\Bbb R
$$
where
$S_n:=\sum_{k=0}^na_n$.

Now you have already checked the first condition; for the second: if $a_n=(-1)^n$ we have that
$$
S_0=a_0=(-1)^0=1\\
S_1=a_0+a_1=1-1=0\\
S_2=S_1+a_2=1-1+1=1
$$
and so on: $S_{2n}=1$ and $S_{2n+1}=0$, and such a sequence doesn't have limit.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to prove for divergence in this case is that the sequence doesn't tend to 0.

Formally, for a series to be convergent:

If $$S_n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$$

$S_n$ is convergent only if $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your counter example??? What I gave above was a necessary, but not sufficient condition for a series to converge. The particular series in the question doesn't satisfy this condition so it does not converge.

Comment: Unless if you can give an example of a series which converges where $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n ≠ 0$, then my above statement remains true.

Comment: OK, this side of the implication is correct.